# Responsive Parallax scrolling change background on media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, parallax

I am creating a parallax scrolling page.
Everything works fine until I open the page on a smartphone.

I have media queries to change the layout.
Here is the setup:

```
<div class="full_width_parallax">
     <div class="wrap_1280">
        <h1 class="intro-tagline">
           Content here
        </h1>
      </div>
 </div>
```

The CSS (for desktop version):

```
.full_width_parallax{
background:url(images/parallax-background/option-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

.wrap_1280{ 
padding: 0 3% 0 3%;
background: #FFF;
opacity: 0.6;
margin: 0 70% 0 3%;
}
```

The CSS (for mobile versions `max-width:480px`)

```
.full_width_parallax{
background:url(images/parallax-background/option-2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
.wrap_1280{ 
margin: 0 3% 0 3%;
}
```

So the only thing changes for the mobile version is the background image and the margin.
If I check the mobile version in chrome (desktop) and run the console it gives me:

[image]

So it should work but doesn't.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'm the dumbest ass at this moment...

The stylesheet for the mobile version is in a folder.
The link in the css for background image didn't had the correct path...

`background:url(images/parallax-background/option-2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

Should have been:
`background:url(../images/parallax-background/option-3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`